# Issues with libgcrypt when starting from a service

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, ppp

I'm currently working on a embedded linux distribution to get networking up and running.
I need it to switch between ppp connection and wifi when it's available. I'm doing this with wpa_cli -a (active mode) like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFNAME=$1
CMD=$2

if [ "$CMD" = "CONNECTED" ]; then
    SSID=`wpa_cli -i$IFNAME status | grep ^ssid= | cut -f2- -d=`
    /usr/bin/poff
fi

if [ "$CMD" = "DISCONNECTED" ]; then
    /usr/bin/pon
fi
```

Pon and poff are for starting and stopping ppp dialing and route setup.

I wrote a simple shell script that starts this, and wpa_supplicant for wlan0 interface:

```
#! bin/sh
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_cli -a/etc/network/networktest.sh -B
/usr/bin/pon
```

I need this to start when the OS boots up so I wrote a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network setup service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/network-setup
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I don't want this to run before wlan0 interface is up and loaded so I created a udev rule that starts the service when wlan0 is up:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan[0]", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="network-setup.service"
```

So here's the issue:
When service is started from the boot and when the os is already up i get this issue:

```
user.warn wpa_supplicant: Libgcrypt warning: missing initialization - please fix the application
```

That issue is only when starting from a service but when I run the script manually it works fine. So why is there an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue

Added:

RemainAfterExit=yes

in the network setup service